# Upgrade to Magento 2.3 to Magento 2.4.4 with Peral theme

Tags: php, dependencies, themes, magento2, upgrade

I am a beginner on magento (I have no experience)

I'm switching from magento 2.3 to magento 2.4, I used this link for the update: https://blog.magezon.com/magento-2-3-to-2-4-upgrade/

when I compile or when I switch to prod mode I have a

> Fatal error:  Declaration of WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Logger::info($message, array $context = Array) must be compatible with Monolog\Logger::info($message, array $context = Array): void in /home/ps41711-1757/www/luzaka-m2-preprod/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Model/Logger.php on line 57.

```
   public function info($message, array $context = array())
    {
        $result = $this->_parseLogMessage($message, $context);
        if ($result !== false) {
            return parent::info($message, $context);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I also updated the theme (Peral Weltpixel)
Does anyone know what to do in this case please?

Comment: So `Logger::info($message, array $context = Array)` must be compatible with `Logger::info($message, array $context = Array): void`

Comment: So have you any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'd add `: void` to the WeltPixel method to make it compatible

Comment: But the function returns somthing, so how can i declare it as a void  ?

Comment: I tried to do what you told then i got :The directory "/www/luzaka-m2/generated/code/Mirasvit" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/www/luzaka-m2/generated/code/Mirasvit): Directory not empty The directory "/home/www/luzaka-m2/generated/code/Magento/Framework" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/www/luzaka-m2-preprod/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty The directory "/home/ps41711-1757/www/luzaka-m2/generated/code/Firebear" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/www/luzaka-m2/generated/code/Firebear): Directory not empty

Comment: Why not contact the developers of that Pearl Theme, you (probably) paid for it. Even if not, they claim it's `FOR MAGENTO 2.0 - 2.4.4` -if it doesn't they should fix that

Comment: We paid 1k for this theme but they take a lot of time to respond
In any case, I really appreciate your participation and your help. :)

Comment: @Shams Did you try to update the Pearl Theme to latest version?